# Max number of simulated wlans with mac80211_hwsim

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, simulation

For some reason when running

**sudo modprobe mac80211_hwsim radios=n**

when n is greater than 100 the comand returns:

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mac80211_hwsim': Invalid argument

is there any limit on simulated radios? because linux kernel page says *mac80211_hwsim is a Linux kernel module that can be used to simulate arbitrary number of IEEE 802.11 radios for mac8021*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source of mac80211_hwsim.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.c?h=v6.0.6#n5279) from the current kernel (6.0.6 as of writing) it is indeed limited to 100:

```
if (radios < 0 || radios > 100)
    return -EINVAL;
```